# Compare and Replace data in table row

Tags: angular, api, frontend, integration

I have an API which fetches data in table rows. It has 2 parameters that it fetches. I have another API which has same two parameters plus 4 more parameters. If 2nd API has any data that is already there in 1st API I want to replace it.

I am able to compare but not display the new data in the table.

```
        res.forEach((el) => {
        const index = this.Array.findIndex((pEl) => {
          return pEl.Name === el.Name;
        });
          if (index >= 0) {
          this.Array[index] = el;
          this.Array[index].Id = el.Id;
          this.Array[index].Name = el.Name;
          this.Array[index].policy= el.policy;
          key.no = el.no;
          key.shift = el.shift;
          key.shifts = el.shifts;
          this.Array[index].checkBox = true;
```

I should be able to check and replace the data.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for this?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to entire coding world and I am not sure how to create the same.